# Pylint is unable to work correctly when the root folder has __init__.py (E0401: Unable to import)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

This is my folder structure:

```
ProjectX/
├── __init__.py
├── PackageY/
│   ├── __init__.py(has import statement - `from PackageY.SubPkgZ.mod1 import 
        mod1fn1`)
│   ├── SubPkgZ
│   │   ├── mod1.py (contains 2 functions: mod1fn1 and mod1fn2)
│   │   ├── __init__.py
```

I am **running pylint from the ProjectX folder** as follows:

```
> pylint PackageY
```

I also tried running:

```
> python -m pylint PackageY
```

Both the above give me the following pylint messages:

```
************* Module ProjectX.PackageY
PackageY\__init__.py:15:0: E0401: Unable to import 'PackageY.SubPkgZ.mod1' (import-error)
```

How can I work around the import error?

In pycharm - If you open the ProjectX and run pylint (via edit configuration) it will not give the import error. So how can I resolve this similarly in the command line run?

Comment: Why does `SubPkgZ` import from `mod1` *via `PackageY`*?

Comment: Please see corrected folder structure now

Comment: Why does `PackageY` import from `SubPkgZ` *via itself*? And why go directly to `mod1`, is `mod1fn1` not exposed via `SubPkgZ/__init__.py`? I don't think the problem here is Pylint, your import structure seems very convoluted.

Comment: `ProjectX` is the root. So all imports are relative to `PackageY`. The `SubPkgZ/__init__.py` is empty

Comment: In pycharm, if I right click on ProjectX folder and mark it as Sources root, and then run pylint PackageY (with working directory as ProjectX) then the error disappears. I think this is got to do with python path, how can I get rid of the import error via command line?

Comment: If `SubPkgZ/__init__.py` is empty but you want to expose `mod1fn1` from `PackageY`, I'd expect to see `from .SubPkgZ.mod1 import mod1fn1`. You could also edit `SubPkgZ/__init__.py` to expose `mod1fn1` explicitly so you could just `from .SubPkgZ import mod1fn1`. That way the imports roll up to the top of the package. If `PackageY/__init__.py` itself imports `... from PackageY...` then you risk circular import problems.

Comment: Sorry I'm using absolute imports. Hence - `from PackageY.SubPkgZ.mod1 import mod1fn1`. I'm confused why does it work with the pycharm hack I mentioned.

Comment: Please provide the bit of that sentence starting "because".

Comment: Ok so do you mean absolute imports don't work with pylint?

Comment: No, that's not what I said. I see you've mentioned the Python path again - on one of your previous attempts I commented a method to check what's on the path, have you used that to investigate this theory? With what results?

Comment: In fact Pylint seems to run just fine on that example. However I see `************* Module PackageY` not `************* Module ProjectX.PackageY`, which makes me think you're missing something out.

Comment: 1) I did try and using the -m flag the current directory gets added to the path. You were right. This is a python feature and hence applicable to pylint as well; 2) Are you running pylint from the ProjectX folder? Because when I do I get `************* Module ProjectX.PackageY`

Comment: 1. OK, so what impact do you think the "Sources root" *is* having? 2. Yes, I'm doing what your example says you're doing.

Comment: 1. The "sources root" adds the ProjectX to the path. I'm so confused right now because I believe that ProjectX and current working directory are the same. But -m adds '' to path (current directory) and surprisingly  "sources root" adds "ProjectX" to the path. And both are the same yet it doesn't work with `-m` and works with "sources root" approach.

Comment: Works fine for me - https://gist.github.com/textbook/6fcc3b7a025364c47a32e09e31a54ed3. I'd suggest you delete this and do more investigation.

Comment: Can you add `__init__.py` under ProjectX folder and re-try; you will see the import error

Comment: That adds more linting issues but doesn't cause any import error; I updated the gist.

Comment: Please see line 49 and 67

Comment: Ah yes - I was looking for something immediately following `************* Module ProjectX.PackageY`.

Comment: Now - 1) If you open the Px folder via pycharm UI and run pylint it will not give the import error. 2) Where as if you open the parent folder of Px and run pylint Py with Px set as working directory then you will see the import error. Now if you right click on Px and set as Sources root then the error disappears. So how can I resolve this similarly in the simple command line run?